# Cocoapods installation permissions error got a little worse

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

First i did

‘’’Gem install cocoapods’’’

And i kept getting this error

‘’’ ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)     You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.’’’

After searching stack overflow for a similar issue I saw a fix with the commands

‘’’ export GEM_HOME=“$HOME/.gem” ‘’’

**I guess exporting my gem home wasn't the fix because now the error is longer and different from before remember all im trying to do is install Cocoapods so I can finish this CRUD tutorial for firebase here is the current error im getting in the terminal**

‘’’ ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
MacBook-Air:CRUD2 macbookpro$ export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
MacBook-Air:CRUD2 macbookpro$ gem install cocoapods
Fetching netrc-0.11.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.10.1.gem
Fetching ffi-1.15.0.gem
Fetching addressable-2.7.0.gem
Fetching typhoeus-1.4.0.gem
Fetching public_suffix-4.0.6.gem
Fetching ethon-0.14.0.gem
Fetching claide-1.0.3.gem
Fetching cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.4.gem
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-search-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-trunk-1.5.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gem
Fetching molinillo-0.6.6.gem
Fetching atomos-0.1.3.gem
Fetching colored2-3.1.2.gem
Fetching nanaimo-0.3.0.gem
Fetching xcodeproj-1.19.0.gem
Fetching escape-0.0.4.gem
Fetching fourflusher-2.3.1.gem
Fetching gh_inspector-1.1.3.gem
Fetching ruby-macho-1.4.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.10.1.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Users/macbookpro/.gem/gems/ffi-1.15.0/ext/ffi_c
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210426-25426-1eeczd5.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-ffi_c-dir
--without-ffi_c-dir
--with-ffi_c-include
--without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
--with-ffi_c-lib
--without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
--enable-system-libffi
--disable-system-libffi
--with-libffi-config
--without-libffi-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` block in try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in` block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in` checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header' from extconf.rb:10:in` system_libffi_usable?'
from extconf.rb:42:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Users/macbookpro/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/macbookpro/.gem/gems/ffi-1.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/macbookpro/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/gem_make.out ‘’’

Comment: Sorry in advance

Comment: This page seems to discuss these issues in depth: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/938

Comment: I have to ask the obvious, are you using a Macbook that is attached to an Admin tool like JAMF? Usually these are devices issued by workplaces.

Comment: @xTwisteDx no this is a macbook I recently purchased

Comment: I fixed it by reinstalling homebrew then rbenv then ruby 
Now i can create a podfile but now its way shorter than tutorials i see any insight? This first screenshot is and the second is my podfile  ![ how its supposed to look ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Hqg.jpg)


![ My pod file] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qqmN.png)